# Удалить часть переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery, файлы, переменные

Есть пременаяя `fileWay` она содержит часть значение что-то типа

```
/home/j/j1343226759b/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/285d48b6dbc39bd882d9b2ca0f52257f.png
```

подскажите пожалуйста как отсечь часть переменной чтобы в итоги получилось типа:

```
sait.ru/uploads/285d48b6dbc39bd882d9b2ca0f52257f.png
```

то есть вырезать `/home/j/j1343226759b` и `public_html`

Comment: А этот путь /home/j/j1343226759b/sait.ru/public_html/uploads у вас всегда стандартный ?

Comment: а не надо такие строки на внешнюю часть сайта вообще вытаскивать. на серверной стороне стройте правильные значения

Comment: Да /home/j/j1343226759b/sait.ru/public_htm/ - всегда стандартно

Comment: ну дак замените `public_html` на пустую строку, и начало тоже.

Comment: ок, спасибо. а как это сделать не подскажете?

Comment: @Grundy а по какой причине вы закрыли этот вопрос и обозначили его как дубликат ? Вообще то этот вопрос был первым, а тот вопрос, который вы указали, и был дубликатом. Вчера тот вопрос был уже отмечен многими как дубликат, но вместо того чтобы тот закрыть, вы закрыли эту ? можно узнать вашу логику ?

Comment: @Arsen, [Может ли старый вопрос считаться дубликатом более нового?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3312/186999)

Comment: @Grundy - да это обсуждение мне знакомо, но если исходить из данной логики, спрашивающий, завтра может ещё раз задать тот же вопрос, и просто добавить что в строке забыл указать какой то символ. Как же быть в данной ситуации ? будете закрывать второй вопрос и оставлять третий ? Неправильно было бы просто поднять первый вопрос в списке для получения более конкретных ответов?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить простое решение։

```
var src = "/home/j/j1343226759b/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/285d48b6dbc39bd882d9b2ca0f52257f.png";
var element = src.split('/');
var newSrc = 'sait.ru/uploads/' + element[element.length - 1];
console.log(newSrc);
```

Comment: /home/j/j1343226759b/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/285d48b6dbc39bd882d9b2ca0f52257f.png - это же у меня переменная. т.е. поменять эту строку на переменную?

Comment: вместо моего src поставьте вашу переменную

Comment: Да, ваш код хорош и понятен. но все оказалась сложнее чем я думал((((

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение
https://regex101.com/r/TrMY4p/1
https://regex101.com/r/TrMY4p/1/codegen?language=javascript
А вообще, это надо делать на стороне сервера. Не нужно светить сервер.